# Автозапуск скрипта при включении windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, автозапуск

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт запускался при каждом запуске windows?
Пробовал так:

```
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0,winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
winreg.SetValueEx(key, "DDoS", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled6\project.py")
key.Close()
```

Когда захожу в автозагрузки, то автозапуск скрипта отключен.

Comment: Добавить его в автозагрузку?

Comment: Положить в скрипты автозапуска станции. GPEDIT.MSC.

Comment: покажите хоть, как вы пытались решить вопрос?

Comment: через планировщик задач не пробовали?

Comment: Сделать exe-шник и закинуть в папку авторуна. Или Вам надо чтобы скрипт сам себя помещал в автозапуск?

Comment: @Kers чтобы сам

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как настроить автозапуск python скрипта на windows 10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220459/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-python-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно проверять наличие только что запущенного скрипта в папке автозагрузки, и если его там нет - копировать туда.

```
import os, sys

Thisfile = sys.argv[0] # Полный путь к файлу, включая название и расширение
Thisfile_name = os.path.basename(Thisfile) # Название файла без пути
user_path = os.path.expanduser('~') # Путь к папке пользователя

if not os.path.exists(f"{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\{Thisfile_name}"):
        os.system(f'copy "{Thisfile}" "{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"')
        print(f'{Thisfile_name} добавлен в автозагрузку')
```

Но это будет работать только в случае, если у вас скрипт скомпилирован в .exe
В противном случае, вам помимо самого скрипта, в папке автозагрузки нужно будет создать **.bat** или **.cmd** файл, который уже будет запускать скрипт в интерпретаторе.

```
@echo off
python PythonCode.py
exit
```