# Как настроить автозапуск python скрипта на windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, systemd

Как настроить автозапуск python скрипта на `windows 10`? Например через `os` или `systemd`. Сам искал-ничего понятного не нашел.

Answer (score -1):

1. Нажать Win+R, ввести shell:startup
2. Добавить туда скрипт и надёжный ярлык на него.
   Готово!

Comment: Надо через код чтобы, а не кнопкой